# Motion in plane

Tags: calculus, integration, analysis, derivatives, definite-integrals

A particle moves in the plane with an acceleration that is parallel to the y-axis and proportional to the distance from the x-axis. If the acceleration is attractive (that is, directed toward the x-axis), then show that the equation of the path may be written in the form $y = A\cos(mx + B)$ .

If the acceleration is repulsive (directed away from the x-axis), on the other hand, then show that the path will be given by an equation of the form $ y = Ae^{mx} + Be^{-mx}$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. I think there is not enough information to solve the problem. Can you explain it further? Besides that, it is advisable to use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for clarity.

Comment: "If the acceleration be attractive...." Attractive to what?

Comment: Proportional? Directly, linearly? Something can be proportional in many ways: logarithmic for one example.

Comment: @FShrike AFAIK if something is logarithmic then it's not proportional. 'Proportional' usually means having a constant ratio ([dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/proportional), [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/proportional), [Camb.Dict.](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/pl/dictionary/english/proportional), [EB](https://www.britannica.com/science/proportionality), ...)

Comment: The questions like "here is my homework, do it for me" are frowned upon here. If you expect some help, you need at least to show your own effort – what you tried and where you stuck. For more hints please see our [Help Center](https://math.stackexchange.com/help) → [Asking](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/asking) → [How do I ask a good question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Would you like to engage with the comments, Pratyush?

Comment: The acceleration is attractive towards the x axis.

Comment: I think that in mathematical terms you are asking to show that the differential equation $${d^2y\over dx^2}=cy$$ has solutions $y=A\cos(mx+b)$ if $c<0$, and $y=Ae^{mx}+Be^{-mx}$ if $c>0$ (where $c$ is constant). Is that so?

Comment: Yes, but the acceleration is attractive so there is a minus sign in the equation.

Comment: No, the way I set it up, the acceleration is attractive if $c<0$. And if you want to be sure I see a comment intended for me, you have to include @Gerry in it.

Comment: Thanks @GerryMyerson